# What is the unit circle in relation to a arbitrary right triangle?

Tags: trigonometry

in an arbitrary right triangle the hypotenuse may be any length, but in the unit circle hypotenuse is always 1, I'am wondering why unit circle doesn't use radius more than 1?

Comment: I am not sure your question makes any sense... What would it even mean for the unit circle to "use radius more than one"?.

Comment: @SBareS thats the question, why the unit circle is always 1, I didn't see any unit circle that is more than 1, but I've seen right triangles where the hypotenuse whas more than 1

Comment: This is a weird question you have, probably mis-understandings. First of all , the hypotenuse isn't **any side** in a triangle. It's specifically named to the *longest one.* Secondly , unit circle implies a circle with unit radius. And why do no not use other radius? Well for trigonometric measures you need **ratios** in a circle not the actual length. And it is convenient to use 1 as radius.

Answer (score 5):

The *unit* circle, by definition, is a circle that has a radius of eactly $1$. $1$ is the unit of multiplication in $\mathbb R$, hence, the *name* unit circle.

Asking why a unit circle has a radius of $1$ is sort of like asking why a cheeseburger has cheese.